# com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings La base de datos tiene transacciones

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

I have a JSF + Spring + Hibernate application. With c3p0 pool v.0.9.1 and then deploying it, the log continuously throws me SQLWarnings as I show below, and do not know why.

The configuration of `c3po` in the spring context is:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
              destroy-method="close">
       <property name="driverClass" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"/>
       <property name="jdbcUrl"
                      value="${url}" />
       <property name="user" value="${user}" />
       <property name="password" value="${password}" />
       <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />   
       <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
       <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="150" />
       <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
       <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
       <property name="numHelperThreads" value="3" />
       <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3600" />     
</bean>
```

The output is:

```
    INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings] La base de datos tiene transacciones
java.sql.SQLWarning: La base de datos tiene transacciones
        at com.informix.util.IfxWarnMsg.getSQLWarning(IfxWarnMsg.java:125)
        at com.informix.util.IfxWarnMsg.getSQLWarning(IfxWarnMsg.java:149)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.addWarning(IfxSqliConnect.java:1817)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setWarnings(IfxSqliConnect.java:3935)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.OpenDbInit(IfxSqliConnect.java:2591)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setDatabaseOpen(IfxSqliConnect.java:2465)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.callsetDatabaseOpen(IfxSqli.java:2496)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeOpenDatabase(IfxSqli.java:1712)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.<init>(IfxSqliConnect.java:1242)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver.connect(IfxDriver.java:243)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2015-03-03 14:22:47,748 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings] Seleccionada base de datos de Informix Dynamic Server 2000
java.sql.SQLWarning: Seleccionada base de datos de Informix Dynamic Server 2000
        at com.informix.util.IfxWarnMsg.getSQLWarning(IfxWarnMsg.java:125)
        at com.informix.util.IfxWarnMsg.getSQLWarning(IfxWarnMsg.java:149)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.addWarning(IfxSqliConnect.java:1817)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setWarnings(IfxSqliConnect.java:3941)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.OpenDbInit(IfxSqliConnect.java:2591)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setDatabaseOpen(IfxSqliConnect.java:2465)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.callsetDatabaseOpen(IfxSqli.java:2496)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeOpenDatabase(IfxSqli.java:1712)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.<init>(IfxSqliConnect.java:1242)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver.connect(IfxDriver.java:243)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731927/c3p0-sqlwarnings-server-user-id-29-is-not-a-valid-user-in-database-defaultdb/21738228#21738228) for a full explanation.

The quick solution if you want to just ignore SQLWarnings is to turn off logging for the logger `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings` in your logging configuration file. (Don't turn off all c3p0 logging, just suppress this one logger.)

A better solution is to figure out why your DBMS/JDBC driver is emitting these warnings, and resolve that. The warnings are there whether you use c3p0 or not. It's just that c3p0 actively checks and logs them, which is something very few applications bother to do.

Also, `c3p0-0.9.1` is now a very old version of the library to use. I strongly recommend you upgrade to the current version, `c3p0-0.9.5`.

Comment: What implications do these SQLWarnings in my application. If they are important or not, since they are related to transactions, and I do not like that my application had not expected behavior for this cause. Thank you very much for your answer, if not important, put out the SQLWarning the log.

Comment: I don't know whether they are important at all; that's an Informix question (maybe you can ask with that tag?)

Comment: (They probably aren't too important. The vast majority of JDBC-using applications never bother to check SQLWarnings. c3p0 is unusual in checking and emitting them by default. Still, better safe than sorry, that you try to understand where they are coming from.)